# How to download pdf url directly in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I don't want to show the pdf file while clicking download, just want to download the file directly.

```
                  <Link
                      target="_blank"
                      href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
                      download="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
                    >
                      Download
                    </Link>
```

Comment: Download or open in browser is determined by header property "Content-Disposition" of http response;

Comment: can I able to change that?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply react `a` tag in `useEffect` and perform click action on it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>PDF</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```